# React(16.8.3) document.getElementById() returning null in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, primereact

After updating Primereact to 8.3.0 document.getElementById() is returning null for div in primereact accordion created in return of jsx.
I was able to access the div returned by the primereact accordion in previous version of primereact 3.4.0.
React version is same in both cases that is 16.8.3

I would like to know how do I access the div returned from primereact accordion using document.getElementById() in componentDidMount.

Answer (score 2):

PrimeReact 8.3.0 requires React 17 or greater and you are using 16.8.3.

See: https://primefaces.org/primereact/setup/

> Please note that react >= 17.0.0 and react-dom >= 17.0.0

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried updating the react version to 17.0.0 but still I am not able to access the div using document.getElementById(). Can you please suggest any other solution for the above issue?

Comment: Can you post your exact code and what you are doing or make a Code Sandbox reproducer: https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-test-forked-bbns8k

Comment: I am having a div inside a primereact accordion as given below:


<Accordion onTabOpen={() => { this.reqPalClick(this.floatwinConfig.content) }}>
<AccordionTab header="Accordion1">
<div id="accordionDiv1" style={{flexGrow: '1', height: '400px', width: "100%", border: 'solid 1px black', alignContent: "left" }}
></div> </AccordionTab>
 </Accordion>

In the above code there is a div with id "accordionDiv1". I want to access this div using document.getElementById in componentDidMount method of jsx